# User must sign in before access some page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I need user to sign in  before access in service page so I have to create function to handle this base on my simple idea

I have 2 function

```
function loggedIn() {
  return false ;
}
```

for check user login or not (I set to false for just to prove my concept) and this function

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/Register'
    })
  }
}
```

to redirect user to register page if user not login yet

```
class App extends Component {




  render() {



    return (

      <div >
      <Header/>

      <Route exact = {true} path = "/" component = {Home} />

      <Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
      <Route path="/promotion" component={Promotion} />
      <Route path="/Service" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
      <Route path="/Service-Tracking" component={Tracking} />
      <Route path="/Service-CreateOrder" component={CreateOrder} />
      <Route path="/Service-Booking" component={Booking} />
      <Route path="/Service-Booking-Dropoff" component={Booking_Dropoff} />
      <Route path="/Service-Booking-Checkinfo" component={Booking_Checkinfo} />
      <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />

      <Footer/>




      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

that's all what inside my App.js  from react-create-app (exclude import file)

but I still can access my service page even though I set loggedIn() to false.

Any Idea?

Thankyou

Comment: Is there any warning/ error on your console ? Also, if you are using react-router 4, instead of onEnter hook for auth stuff, you can give <Redirect /> a try. You can check their official documentation => https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Comment: @CagriYardimci Thanks!! i will try it soon  :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do this. (You can adapt this to suit your needs) This came originally from a firebase boilerplate but the protected functions should give you an idea.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Link, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './Login'
import Register from './Register'
import Home from './Home'
import Dashboard from './protected/Dashboard'
import { logout } from '../helpers/auth'
import { firebaseAuth } from '../config/constants'

function PrivateRoute ({component: Component, authed, ...rest}) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => authed === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
    />
  )
}

function PublicRoute ({component: Component, authed, ...rest}) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => authed === false
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/dashboard' />}
    />
  )
}

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    authed: false,
    loading: true,
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    this.removeListener = firebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({
          authed: true,
          loading: false,
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          authed: false,
          loading: false
        })
      }
    })
  }
  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.removeListener()
  }
  render() {
    return this.state.loading === true ? <h1>Loading</h1> : (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="navbar-header">
                <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">React Router + Firebase Auth</Link>
              </div>
              <ul className="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li>
                  <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/dashboard" className="navbar-brand">Dashboard</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {this.state.authed
                    ? <button
                        style={{border: 'none', background: 'transparent'}}
                        onClick={() => {
                          logout()
                        }}
                        className="navbar-brand">Logout</button>
                    : <span>
                        <Link to="/login" className="navbar-brand">Login</Link>
                        <Link to="/register" className="navbar-brand">Register</Link>
                      </span>}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
                <PublicRoute authed={this.state.authed} path='/login' component={Login} />
                <PublicRoute authed={this.state.authed} path='/register' component={Register} />
                <PrivateRoute authed={this.state.authed} path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
                <Route render={() => <h3>No Match</h3>} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```